Hibernate 6 : Combine Customise generator with Hibernate Provided generator
My Setup:
Mysql 5.7
hibernate 6.4.4
Spring boot 3.2.2
here is the class that I used in Hibernate 5 to generate id
public class UseExistingIdOtherwiseGenerateUsingIdentity extends IdentityGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
        return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
    }
}

after migrating to hibernate 6 this is failing as IdentityGenerator does not have generate method
I used IdentifierGenerator problem with this is it can cause in duplicate primary keys how to make a custom generator that can use MySQL's Auto Increment if Id is not provided else use the provided id
referred https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-combine-the-hibernate-assigned-generator-with-a-sequence-or-an-identity-column/ but it seems it is obsolete
